# Heap growth related to use of CCLabelTTF

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4, heap-memory

I am using `Cocos2d 1.01`. I am having undesired heap growth. To identify what is causing the growth I took a baseline snapshot, did a state change and return to zero state and repeated the heapshot.  I found the primary cause of the heap growth to be `non-object` and then looked at the stack trace, noting that the problematic code appeared to be centered around `CCLabelTTF`.

Here is the code that seems to be problematic:

```
    NSString *desc = [pEffectDescriptions objectAtIndex:i];
    CCLabelTTF *descrptionLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:desc dimensions:CGSizeMake(290, 65) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"Verdana-Italic" fontSize:10];
    descrptionLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    descrptionLabel.color = ccc3(192, 192, 192);
    descrptionLabel.position = ccp(aSprite.position.x + 8, aSprite.position.y);
    [self addChild:descrptionLabel z:10 tag:COMPARTMENT0+9600+i];
```

I don't understand what the problem is, because before returning to state zero, the following code is executed:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    if ([self getChildByTag:COMPARTMENT0+9000+i])
        [self removeChildByTag:COMPARTMENT0+9000+i cleanup:true];
}
```

My reasoning is that the `CCLabelTTF` is owned by the layer and it in turn owns the `NSString` (the array also retains the `NSString`).  However, when I remove the `CCLabelTTF` from the layer and its dealloc gets called it should therefore release the `CCLabelTTF`, which would then dealloc.  Could the array reference to the `NSString` be responsible for preventing the deallocation of `CCLabelTTF`?

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

While adding labels you add 9600 to the tag, while removing you only add 9000 to the tag. Could that be it?

PS: I suggest using bitmap fonts, they use less memory, create, update and render faster.

Comment: Unfortunately no, because it indexes from 9000 - 9999 and the first loop is just 55-100 items.  Such a weird problem.  Some little stupid thing I did somewhere but try to find it.  The thing is, the retained items are there even when I pop the scene, and I NSLog'd the dealloc method so everything should get wiped out.